# Multidimensional array - dimmension of input array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am doing course in Hyperskill platform - Introduction to Java. I am facing with an error of compilation which is not described anywhere (**Failed test #6 of 8. Wrong answer**)

Would you be able to look into my code and help me?

Please see the task description.

You need to implement `printCorners` method. It should print all corner elements of the `twoDimArray` in the following order: left to right and top to bottom.

The elements must be separated by space and printed as an example below.

Input array:

```
1 0 2
0 0 0
3 0 4
```

Printed corners:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Notice, that you must always print 4 corners, for example:

Input array:

```
1
2
3
```

Printed corners:

```
1 1
3 3
```

code:

```java
public class ArrayOperations {
    public static void printCorners(int[][] twoDimArray) {
        int n = 2;
        int[][] myTable = new int[n][n];
        int cols = twoDimArray[0].length;
        if (cols == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    myTable[0][0] = twoDimArray[i][0];
                    myTable[0][1] = twoDimArray[i][0];
                    myTable[1][0] = twoDimArray[i][0];
                    myTable[1][1] = twoDimArray[i][0];
                }
                else if (i < twoDimArray.length - 1) {
                    myTable[1][0] = twoDimArray[i][0];
                    myTable[1][1] = twoDimArray[i][0];
                }
            }
            System.out.println(myTable[0][0] + " " + myTable[0][0]);
            System.out.println(myTable[1][0] + " " + myTable[1][1]);
        }
        else if (cols > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < twoDimArray[i].length; j++) {
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                        myTable[0][0] = twoDimArray[i][j];
                    }
                    else if (i == 0 && j == twoDimArray[i].length - 1) {
                        myTable[0][1] = twoDimArray[i][j];
                    }
                    else if (i == twoDimArray.length - 1 && j == 0) {
                        myTable[1][0] = twoDimArray[i][j];
                    }
                    else if (i == twoDimArray.length - 1 && j == twoDimArray[i].length - 1) {
                        myTable[1][1] = twoDimArray[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < myTable.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < myTable[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(myTable[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be making this more complicated than it needs to be. The indexes of the corner elements can easily be determined as follows:

- top left = 0, 0
- top right = 0, length of row minus one
- bottom left = number of rows minus one, 0
- bottom right = number of rows minus one, length of row minus one

```java
public class ArrayOperations {
    public static void printCorners(int[][] twoDimArray) {
        int n = 2;
        int[][] myTable = new int[n][n];
        myTable[0][0] = twoDimArray[0][0];
        myTable[0][1] = twoDimArray[0][twoDimArray[0].length - 1];
        myTable[1][0] = twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1][0];
        myTable[1][1] = twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1][twoDimArray[0].length - 1];
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
                System.out.print(myTable[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printCorners(new int[][]{{1}, {2}, {3}});
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        printCorners(new int[][]{{1, 0, 2},
                                 {0, 0, 0},
                                 {3, 0, 4}});
    }
}
```

Running above code produces following output:

```
1 1 
3 3 
====================================================================
1 2 
3 4
```

Comment: Your're right, I did more complex solution, than it's actually needed. Anyway thank you for the input. Everything is right to the point!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is full java based solution:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class ArrayOperations {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] multiDimensionalArray1 = {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}
        };
        
        int[][] multiDimensionalArray2 = {
            {1, 2},
            {4, 5}
        };

        int[][] multiDimensionalArray3 = {
            {1}
        };
        
        
        
        int[][] transformedArray1 = transformToMultiDimensionalArray(multiDimensionalArray1, 2);
        int[][] transformedArray2 = transformToMultiDimensionalArray(multiDimensionalArray2, 2);
        int[][] transformedArray3 = transformToMultiDimensionalArray(multiDimensionalArray3, 2);
   
        for (int[] subarray : transformedArray1) {
            for (int element : subarray) {
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
     
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        
        for (int[] subarray : transformedArray2) {
            for (int element : subarray) {
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        

        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        
        for (int[] subarray : transformedArray3) {
            for (int element : subarray) {
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[][] transformToMultiDimensionalArray(int[][] matrix, int elementsPerSubarray) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;

        if (rows == 1 && cols == 1) {
            return new int[][]{{matrix[0][0]}};
        }

        List<Integer> corners = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
                    corners.add(matrix[row][col]); // first element first row
                } else if (row == 0 && col == cols - 1) {
                    corners.add(matrix[row][col]); // last element first row
                } else if (row == rows - 1 && col == 0) {
                    corners.add(matrix[row][col]); // first element last row
                } else if (row == rows - 1 && col == cols - 1) {
                    corners.add(matrix[row][col]); // last element last row
                }
            }
        }

        int[][] multiDimensionalArray = new int[corners.size() / elementsPerSubarray][elementsPerSubarray];
        for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++) {
            int row = i / elementsPerSubarray;
            int col = i % elementsPerSubarray;
            multiDimensionalArray[row][col] = corners.get(i);
        }

        return multiDimensionalArray;
    }
}
```

**This is not from Java. I've used javascript. For presentational purposes, I've adopted javascript based answer for this. But logic remains the same as above java solution.**

Refer the code below:

```js
function printCornerElements(matrix, elementsPerSubarray) {
  let rows = matrix.length;
  let cols = matrix[0].length;

  if (rows === 1 && cols === 1) { 
    return [matrix[0][0]];
  }

  let corners = [];

  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      if (row === 0 && col === 0) {
        corners.push(matrix[row][col]); // first element first row
      } else if (row === 0 && col === cols - 1) {
        corners.push(matrix[row][col]); // last element first row
      } else if (row === rows - 1 && col === 0) {
        corners.push(matrix[row][col]); // first element last row
      } else if (row === rows - 1 && col === cols - 1) {
        corners.push(matrix[row][col]); // last element last row
      }
    }
  }
  
  let multiDimensionalArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < corners.length; i += elementsPerSubarray) {
    let subarray = corners.slice(i, i + elementsPerSubarray);
    multiDimensionalArray.push(subarray);
  }

  return multiDimensionalArray;
}

const multiDimensionalArray1 = [
  [1, 2,3],
  [4, 5,6],
  [7, 8,9],

];

const multiDimensionalArray2 = [
  [1, 2],
  [4, 5],

];

const multiDimensionalArray3 = [
  [1]
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(printCornerElements(multiDimensionalArray1,2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(printCornerElements(multiDimensionalArray2,2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(printCornerElements(multiDimensionalArray3,2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to implement `printCorners` method. It should print all corner elements of the `twoDimArray` in the following order: left to right and top to bottom.

Since all you are asked to do is print the arrays, there is no need to build a new array. Also evidenced by the method being declared void and does not permit the return of the created array.

**Some test Data**

```
int[][] a1 = {{1},{2},{3}};
int[][] a2 = {{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{4,5,6,7}};
int[][] jagged = {{1},{2,3},{3,4},{5,6,7,7}};
```

**The Method**

To make it easy, define some positions

- `lri` -  last row index
- `lifr` - last index of first row
- `lilr` - last index of last row

```
public static void printCorners(int[][] arr) {
    int lri = arr.length-1;
    int lifr = arr[0].length-1;
    int lilr = arr[lri].length-1;
    System.out.printf("%d %d%n", arr[0][0],arr[0][lifr]);
    System.out.printf("%d %d%n", arr[lri][0],arr[lri][lilr]);
}
printCorners(a1);  System.out.println();
printCorners(a2);  System.out.println();
printCorners(jagged);  System.out.println();
```

prints

```
1 1
3 3

1 4
4 7

1 1
5 7
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution!